# What is 'ForceArray=> qr/^(logentry|path)$'?

Tags: python, perl, svn

```
use strict;
use XML::Simple;

# $ARGV[0] = <revision_number>
# $ARGV[1] = <https://svn_path>
# $ARGV[2] = <branch>
   
 my $command = `svn log -v --xml -rHEAD:$ARGV[0] $ARGV[1]/$ARGV[2]/some_dir/`;
 eval { $ref = XMLin($command, ForceArray=> qr/^(logentry|path)$/); };
 die "Cannot read xml output of svn log -v --xml -rHEAD:$ARGV[0]: $@" if($@);
```

Came across this perl snippet. Could make out that it's executing `svn` log command.
`XMLin` is something to read xml contents, I believe (use XML::Simple)

Writing equivalent code in python. Started reading `perl` after looking at this syntax. Finding it difficulty in understanding it. What's `ForceArray` and `qr/^(logentry|path)$/`?

How can I write the same in python (`eval`)?
Are any tools/scripts available to translate `perl` to `python` ?

Comment: `ForceArray` is one of the options that you use to influence the way XML::Simple guesses about how you would like it to treat your data. As the author of XML::Simple I would suggest that it's not a module you ought to be using in Perl and certainly not one you should be emulating in any other language. I'm afraid there's no short cut here, you simply need to read what the Perl code is doing and write Python code to do it using a proper XML DOM module.

Comment: what it does here ForceArray=> qr/^(logentry|path)$/ ?

Comment: `qr/^(logentry|path)$/` is a regular expression which will match the name of `<logentry>` or `<path>` elements in the XML, so the [ForceArray option](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#ForceArray-=%3E-1-%23-in-important) is enabled for only those elements.  The job of the `XMLin()` function is to slurp an XML document into a Perl data structure made up of plain arrays, hashes (dictionaries) and scalar values (strings & numbers). The `ForceArray` option tells `XMLin()` to always represent the selected elements as an array - even if there is only one.

Comment: `=>` is a fancy kind of comma - see https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Comma-Operator

Answer (score 0):

```perl
ForceArray=> qr/^(logentry|path)$/
```

is equivalent to

```perl
"ForceArray", qr/^(logentry|path)$/
```

The direct equivalent in Python would be

```py
"ForceArray", regex.compile(r"^(logentry|path)$")
```

But it's acting as a keyword (named) argument, so a more accurate Python equivalent would be

```py
ForceArray=regex.compile(r"^(logentry|path)$")
```

This particular argument affects the structure being returned by `XMLin`.

You shouldn't be using XML::Simple in Perl, much less recreating it in Python. Use a proper parser and adjust the code accordingly.

---

The Python equivalent to `eval BLOCK` is a `try` statement.

```perl
eval { ... };
die "..." if($@);
```

is similar to

```py
try:
   ...
except ...:
   ...
```